# How to run listener.cpp on PC to receive message from Android (using Rosjava)?

Tags: ros, c++, network, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The goal is to send message from Android and receive it on my PC.
My idea is to use [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) tutorial to build a package on PC containing an executable "listener".
Then I write an android application based on rosjava. and set the MasterUri to PC (which is http://192.168.13.7:11311)
my code is like this:

```
String hostLocal = InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostAddress();
String hostMaster = "192.168.13.7";
URI uri = URI.create("http://" + hostMaster + ":" + "11311");
NodeConfiguration nodeConfigurationTalker = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(hostLocal, uri);

talker = new Talker;
nodeRunner.run(tistener, nodeConfigurationTalker);
```

Then I started roscore on PC and talker on android AVD (target 10), remembering to
`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 and export ROS_IP=192.168.13.7.`

but then there occurs this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:java.net.ConnectException:10.0.2.15/10.0.2.15:58353 - Connection refused
```

roswtf suggests Could not connect the android Node. and of course i couldn't receive anything on my pc...

I wonder what could be the cause. Do I need to set up anything else to combine c++ and rosjava? what could be the correct network setup? Is there any tutorial which is intended for communication between android and PC? The android_tutorial_pubsub builds its roscore in android itself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30681/how-to-run-listener.cpp-on-pc-to-receive-message-from-android-(using-rosjava)?/) by [rosdai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2053/rosdai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using the emulator, this will likely never work. See http://answers.ros.org/question/30018/rosjava-on-android-emulator

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0